# Tibco EMS, run server from command promt

Tags: tibco-ems

When I'm running TIBCO from different location in the command prompt, it cannot find the configuration, for example in such case:

```
c:\Work\Projects>EMSServer\4.4.3\bin\tibemsd.exe

2014-10-27 15:01:15 Warning: configuration file 'tibemsd.conf' not found and has been created. All configuration settings have been reset to defaults.
2014-10-27 15:01:15 Process started from 'EMSServer\4.4.3\bin\tibemsd.exe'.
```

Probably it looks for the configuration in the Current Working Directory (I mean location from where it was run).

Is it possible to point TOBCO to look in correct location?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick ;)

tibemsd.exe -config  *path-to-your-folder*/tibemsd.conf

Comment: I've tried this, but it shows that cannot find users.conf. And it doesn't support passing users.conf as a parameter.

Comment: Hello Roman, There's links in your tibemsd.conf that point to several other config files like the users.conf file.                      Check if you find a line like this and check where it points at the moment: users                   = "...path.../users.conf"